# Sending an Intent to Google Maps with pre-defined route?

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to send an Intent to Google Maps app so that it starts navigation for a pre-defined route. I believe this can be done by specifying waypoints.

Right now, I can only get Google Maps to recognise the start, destination parameters. I could not find a way to include waypoints in the Intent URI.

```
    String url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=13.824615009125084,100.51791250705719&daddr=13.7464,100.5350";

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
```

I have tried doing something like this, but no luck.

```
    String url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=San+Francisco,+CA&daddr=Los+Angeles,+CA+to:Phoenix,+AZ+to:Houston,+TX+to:Jacksonville,+FL+to:New+York,+NY+to:Buffalo,+NY+to:Chicago,+IL+to:Seattle,+WA+to:San+Jose,+CA";
```

Google Maps just kept saying "No results for [starting point]."

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current%20Location&daddr=53.299996, -8.744618"));
                    startActivity(myWebLink);
```